# Ng-click inside of ng-click AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a link that uses `ng-click` inside of a table row which also uses the `ng-click` directive.

When I click on the link, both `ng-click` directives fire. How can I adjust them so that only the most specific one (remove item) fires?

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="viewItem(item.id)">
   <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
   <td><a ng-click="removeItem(item.id, 'item.name')">Remove item</a></td>
 </tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to stop the event from bubbling by using `stopPropagation()`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="viewItem(item.id)">
   <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
   <td><a ng-click="removeItem(item.id, 'item.name'); $event.stopPropagation()">Remove item</a></td>
 </tr>
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LRAXb/)